# Possible to prevent our website from running inside another domain's frameset or IFrame?

Tags: javascript, dns, frame, frameset-iframe

We've been having an problem recently where other sites are running our e-commerce site inside a frameset where our site (with the offenders affiliate id tacked on) is the only content in a single full width frame.  So essentially it looks and feels like our site with their URL at the top.  We can cut off their affiliate id, which would make it pointless for them to do, but this doesn't prevent future offenders from doing the same thing until we find out about it.

Is there a generic way (through JavaScript that appears on every page perhaps?) to prevent this from happening?  Note that adding targets to to all links is not feasible, but adding a snippet of JS to all pages is, since the header and footer portions are shared sitewide from a single source.

Another possibility would be at the Apache level (if there is anything we could do server side) as we do pass all requests through mod-rewrite.

Note that it would be essential to sill allow pages to load inside an IFrame if the parent page originates from our domain, as we make valid use of IFrames

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the proper modern method to achieve this is with [The X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).

From the MDN:

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a frame or iframe. Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

Take a look at: [How to prevent IFRAME from redirecting top-level window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369498/how-to-prevent-iframe-from-redirecting-top-level-window?rq=1)

Comment: This is the correct answer for 2017. OWASP has a great [Clickjacking Defense Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet) that discusses the attack and remediation possibilities.

Comment: I've updated the chosen answer to my old question given modern best practices

Answer (score 6):

I've heard of solutions to this problem being referred to as a "frame popper script". A quick google comes up with [this thread](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/3226698.htm). Looks like this is one of the simplest:

```
if (window != top) top.location.href = location.href;
```

Comment: That would be quite nifty, the hacking site trying to 'Iframe' your site, would be redirected to your site in the parent window :)

Comment: you can also write this as `if(top !== self) top.location.href = self.location.href` - same thing, but more symmetric

Comment: There are workarounds to many of these "frame popper scripts",
 so they should no longer be used. See OWASP [Clickjacking Defense Cheat Sheet: Insecure Non-Working Scripts DO NOT USE](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Insecure_Non-Working_Scripts_DO_NOT_USE)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this article. It offers a fairly simple solution for detecting frames and breaking out of them.

[How to Break Out of Frames with JavaScript](http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/framebreak.shtml)

In addition, I would take it one step further. Whenever you detect a frame, grab the affiliate ID of the offending site framer, and push that to the server with AJAX along with the URL they are using. Then, either automatically or manually, you can verify that they are framing your site, and cancel their affiliate code one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here...but what if you use javascript to call your parent window to access its document object ? You could check if its not null, and if there is a parent window (meaning a frame loaded your site), you could hide all your html through javascript...