# blocking frames and iframes with javascript

Tags: javascript, frameset-iframe

I have been looking for a solution to prevent loading of my site from anywhere other than my site. Meaning can I prevent or at least put measure in place to deter loading of my site in frames and iframes from other sites. I have seen some useful answers here for similar questions but I was wondering about going at it from another direction. Is it possible to onload check browser url if anything other than www.mysite.com/ then force reload of www.mysite.com/ . Can this be done in javascript as my familiarity of other languages is limited. 
Here is an example of the code I was trying but it isn't working the way I want. It is reloading the iframe only and allowing the the leaching site to remain. I need to force a full page reload to my site. What am I missing?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    <!-- 
    if( -1 == location.href.
       toLowerCase().
       indexOf('mysite.com') )
    {
      location.href = 'http://mysite.com';
    }
    // -->
    </script>
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459835/possible-to-prevent-our-website-from-running-inside-another-domains-frameset-or?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

List of FrameBusters available from [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/3226698.htm) and pasted below for future reference.

---

1.

`if (window.top!=window.self){window.top.location="thepage_the_buster_is_on.php";}`

2.

`if (top.location!= location) {top.location.replace(self.location.href);}`

3.

`if( window!= window.top ) {top.location.href = location.href;}`

4.

`if (top.location!= location) {top.location.href = document.location.href;}`

5.

`if (parent.frames.length > 0) top.location.replace(document.location);`

Comment: I don't think this works. You cannot modify the top location from a different domain.

Comment: so it is not possible to load a new page from within a frame/iframe. I am sure I have seen codes before that allow an iframe to load a new page upon click. I just want it to happen upon load if url = anything other than mine?

Comment: Kazzzaaa Thanks Asryael. I tried your code and unfortunately it crashed my site. Not sure why but any way I grab just the top line from you and that seems to do exactly what I wanted. The site that was leeching me is now reloading my site every time it trys to put me in an iframe. Here what I used.

        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        <!-- 

        if (window.top!=window.self) {window.top.location="http://mysite.com";}


    // -->
    </script>

Comment: yes thank you Asryael I used just part of your script but it did the trick. Many thanks

Comment: @DavidJohnson please mark as answer on the left if this helped you.

Comment: the replace() function takes two arguements i think in Js..

Comment: Thank you for these solutions! Just want to add a comment since this is almost 9 years old now, and things change: Solution 1 did not seem to work - I got an alert in Chrome that the redirect was blocked. Solutions 2, 3, and 4 all worked. Solution 5 gave an endless reload loop.