# Google Docs in iframe AND Save & Close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox, modalpopups

I am using Google Docs in my project using its API.

I am loading docs in modal window iframe using http://fancybox.net/ a jquery plugin

It works fine but when in Google Docs **Save and Close** button is press, it closes the iframe and redirects the current page to Google Docs, So is there any way I can prevent the redirection to Google Docs and just close the modal window?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few other questions i've found on SO that deal with this type of question;

[How to prevent IFRAME from redirecting top-level window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369498/how-to-prevent-iframe-from-redirecting-top-level-window)

[How to prevent IFRAME from redirecting top-level window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369498/how-to-prevent-iframe-from-redirecting-top-level-window)

Basically it involves using the 'window.onbeforeunload' function to kill the iframe if it attempts to redirect.