# Redirect parent window from iFrame

Tags: asp.net, javascript, iframe

I have an asp.net page inside an iFrame. I want to redirect the parent page (that sits outside the iFrame) when an asp.net button on the asp.net page in the iFrame is clicked.

The asp.net button will need to do some processing before re-directing, so I guess I need to call javascript from the asp.net

Comment: Duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788125/asp-net-how-to-redirect-to-another-web-site-from-a-page-inside-a-frame/2788219#2788219

Comment: It is similar, but I want to only enact the javascript AFTER the asp.net function has been called from the button

Comment: Which means that it is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

just create simple ans: in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function NewWindow() {
        document.forms[0].target = "_top";
    }
</script>
```

call it any control like button

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkbutton1" Text="Enroll Now" OnClientClick="NewWindow();" runat="server" onclick="enrol_Click"/>
```