# Redirect to new website and back to original website asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I have a scenario where I need to call a website B from Website A using ASP.NET. Once the work on website B is done, the user needs to be redirected to the same page on Website A.

Website A --> Website B --> Website A

This is similar to the behavior of a e-commerce site calling paypal and returning back to the e-commerce site

Please help in achieving this.

Comment: Do you have control over Website B?

Comment: I have control over website B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say most sites achieve that behavior by following the next scheme:

- Website A requests a url in the domain of Website B, sending some sort of *callback mechanism*, most likely, a **return url**
- Website B remembers the return url from A, does the processing it needs to do, and then simple directs the user back to site A by issuing a request to the Return Url provided by Website A.
- Website A acts accordingly, since it knows Website B used a the return url which was specifically created to handle users that are coming back after a short visit to Website B.

To avoid fake requests between the servers, a "temporal token" is usually used between the 2 sites so that their "talking" is *protected*.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to call the website B in a "Frame" and depending on the logic you could have a return url for Website A.

[ASP.NET How to redirect to another web site from a page inside a frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788125/asp-net-how-to-redirect-to-another-web-site-from-a-page-inside-a-frame)