# prevent html page from open a new window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a html based application and sometimes my html app needs to open another url in iframe.
the problem is that the third party url in the iframe open a new window too with the same content, the same url.
so how can i prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an iframe breakoutscript in the thirdparty page.  A few links about a solution to this problem.

http://stuntsnippets.com/prevent-iframe-breakout/

http://www.zimbio.com/Web+Design/articles/1110/How+prevent+iFrame+breakaway

[How to prevent IFRAME from redirecting top-level window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369498/how-to-prevent-iframe-from-redirecting-top-level-window)

Comment: no. those links represents three methods to deal with iframe breakout. 1. the security attribute which disable the javascript inside the iframe - not good 2. using php to remove the iframe breakout code - not good to and 3. using onbeforeunload method which invoke message to user - not good to. I think there is no solution for that except a hack which i can't find on the net too.

Comment: Why aren't these methods good enough, they deal with iframe breakout which is the problem you are faced with.