# How to prevent new tab, new window and any popups while browsing website inside iframe of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

When I browse some other sites put inside "iframe" in my site,
the original site opens new tab or new page if I click some buttons.
So it blocks my site and nobody can close the new tab or new site.
Because my site is opened as full-screen size (F11 mode) without keyboard as like an outdoor billboard or kiosk.

I`ve tried to find out the way to prevent new tab, new window and any popups while browsing website inside "iframe" of HTML.

And I`ve seen many answers with their solution codes, but nothing works yet.

So first, I am wondering whether it is possible or not.
If it is possible to prevent new tab or new window when browsing site inside iframe, I`m looking for a solution.

Comment: StackOverflow has multiple answers relating to your question. Please enlist what have you tried so far.

Comment: I`ve tried to refer the codes in the StackOverflow below. 1.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419034/how-to-prevent-opening-new-tab-or-window-while-browsing-in-iframe

Comment: I also read many time this. 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064798/prevent-html-page-from-open-a-new-window

Comment: 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188009/how-to-prevent-links-in-iframe-from-opening-in-new-tab

Comment: I found many multiple answers as you said, but I couldn`t find something working. I`ve searched using these key sentences "prevent new tab in iframe" or "block opening new tab or new window in iframe" in StackOverflow.