# how to prevent when a website is blocking its usage within an iframe tag

Tags: javascript, iframe

In my website, I preview any link with a tooltip, but when its facebook or meneame.net, for example; they block it and open their webiste in you website's current window.

Exanple `<iframe src="http://meneame.net/bababa"></iframe>`

How can i prevent that? i mean, maybe open it in a '_blank'  page instead would be perfect for me. is it possible?

PD: the option of trying to detect which URL is about to be opened its not valid for me as long I don't know all the websites that do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is due to the "same origin policy". It was design specifically to prevent wrapping pages from hijacking iframe content. It's a security feature. If we could circumvent this all browsers will then be insecure.

Comment: The thing is that i don't want to show it in my page if 'they' don't 'want' but i just want to detect that and be able to abort instead of bein redirected. Do you think that is posible?

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369498/how-to-prevent-iframe-from-redirecting-top-level-window

Comment: I had a very interesting reading and realised that if user wants  to come back they only have to 'back' and if not, where is the point. Thanks a lot!