# php iframe keep redirecting websites within frame

Tags: php, iframe

I have an iframe that renders websites (like http://google.com).  However for websites that redirect (like http://tinyurl.com/l6llqre), the redirect will open within the entire window of my current browser.  How do I fix it so that the website will redirect within the iframe??

Here's my iframe:

```
public function renderContent() {
  if ($this->url) {
    return
     <iframe
       src={$this->url}
       width="100%"
       height="500px"
       scrolling="no"
     />;
  } else {
    return <ui:box type="red">{'The website cannot be loaded'}</ui:box>;
  }
}
```

Really new at php, would appreciate any tips!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent IFRAME from redirecting top-level window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369498/how-to-prevent-iframe-from-redirecting-top-level-window)

Comment: if a site want to break out of your iframe you should let it

Comment: I'm not sure if they can break out of embeds but trying embed is worth a shot.