# HTML: iframe sandbox alternatives

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Some websites has a script that will redirect it to the original site if you tried to put it on an iframe. So to solve this, we have add the property [`sandbox="allow-scripts"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369498/how-to-prevent-iframe-from-redirecting-top-level-window#answer-9880360) to the iframe tag. But this solution will not work on browser that doesn't support html5. How can we resolve this? Additionally, we still want to have the script activated on the inner pages.

Comment: What's the -1 for? ~_~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask the owners/administrators of the site to give you an authenticated URL for the site that doesn't redirect.

If you're trying to do this without the permission of the owners/adminstrators, then please reconsider your design.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the original post is mentioning a frame-busting script which is in place to keep the page contents from being framed, usually to combat click-jacking attacks.

If you have permission from the site you are trying to frame, aka you have a legitimate reason to be framing their site, you should work with the owners of that site to find a work around. One such method would be to have them replace their frame-busting script with an X-Frame-Options header that could list your domain as an allowed domain to frame the content.