# stop override all JavaScript redirect .. only allow a click

Tags: javascript

I have issue with mobile website.. which are I cant track-down, it may be from malware on user phone or maybe adnetwork.. only few visitor got this issue

when user visit my web.. they will redirect to other website mobiphone-tips or cellphone-tips and it random very few time days, normally in fist time of day only.

I'm trying looking the way to override all default redirect javascipt to return false, so keep user stay on page.. they only go as they wish when click on a links

i have tried with window.onbeforeunload place on header .. but this also stop user from click a link

Please help

Comment: do you have an ads iframe?

Comment: my website is: xaluan.com (please run from mobile device for test) the issue only fews so very hard to reproduces this.. i use chrome inspect element, fiddle, debug ect to track it down but still no clue.. I have tried look for solution..there are too many topic about this.. all they go nowhere .. some tell it is malware on phone, change dns, some say it is thirt party adsnetwork.. .. 
@LiYinKong yes and maybe.. the adsnetwork may have iframe for the banner from buyer.. but as i know redirect from iframe is restricted to the main frame in browser..

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369498/how-to-prevent-iframe-from-redirecting-top-level-window

Comment: @LiYinKong thank for information.. have you got any ideal for my case, prevent any call from javascript change href of main current webpage?